# Асинхронное чтение файлов

Tags: asp.net, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Есть коллекция файлов в файловой системе на сервере. При входящем запросе необходимо считать все эти файлы и провести действия с данными. Можно ли сделать это асинхронно? Тоесть на выходе нужна коллекция результатов действия по каждому файлу.

Answer (score 2):

- Правильный способ - применить схему `Producer-Consumer` с единственным читающим тредом и пулом рабочих тредов, которые будут выполнять операции над файлами.
- То есть, грубо говоря, читающий тред добавляет некоторый таск, который подхватывается `worker thread'ами`, и для всех тасков делается `WaitForAll,` пока не будет получен финальный результат.

> - Единственный читающий тред имеет смысл в предположении, что параллельное чтение на порядок хуже, нежели сихронное.
> - См. [**Is Parallel File.Read Faster than Sequential Read?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237926/is-parallel-file-read-faster-than-sequential-read)

- Изучение вопроса можно начать с [`[MSDN]` Task.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.task)

Comment: Спасибо, будем пробовать